# aspose pdf v 21.8 only work till .net 5, After upgrade to .net 6, I don't want to upgrade aspose pdf version

Tags: .net-6.0, aspose.pdf

`License license = new License(); license.SetLicense("MyLicence");` //get exception system.Exception

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: The .NET 6 support was added in the API after it was released. Please try to use 21.12 or the latest version of the API in order to get your issue resolved. This is Asad and I am Developer Evangelist at Aspose.